# How to Use Command Line Arguments to Dictate Flow of Program?

Tags: java, methods, command-line-arguments

I have scoured all of Google it seems and I cannot find anything regarding how to use command line arguments to tell the Java program which subsequent method to perform. I am trying to create a Java program with several different aspects of a student grading application.

The main program is a GUI form where the user can input grades for each student in a specific class. Along with this, I need a control program that accepts 3 command arguments. The first is a number to indicate the type of file to load (1. XML 2. JSON 3. TXT). The second is a letter to indicate the file material (C indicates Course data, S indicates Student data). The last argument is the name of the specific data file to upload, which will then be extracted and uploaded to a database to be used by the GUI program.

I have the rest of the program already coded except for the command arguments because I have absolutely no idea what I am doing. The command argument code is supposed to look *something* like this:

```
public class Load
{
    //Define global variables
    static String inputDataChoice;
    static String inputTableChoice;
    static String inputFileName;

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        if (userChose == arg[0], arg[3], arg[5])
        {
            //If user chose 1 (XML), S (Student), and xmltest.xml
            //Go to ParseXMLStudentFile();
        }

        if (userChose == arg[1], arg[4], arg[6])
        {
            //If user chose 2 (JSON), C (Course), and jsontest.json
            //Go to ParseJSONCourseFile();
        }

        if (userChose == arg[2], arg[3], arg[7])
        {
            //If user chose 3 (TXT), S (Student), and test.txt
            //Go to ParseTXTStudentFile();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the above code is bogus, but that is the general idea. How do I accept command arguments from the user and then use that input to decide which method is executed? Would this program use the console window to accept user input? Please help!

Comment: You need to walk before you can run. If you don't know basic java `if` statements, you won't get very far,

Comment: @John3136 Thanks but I know basic Java. Just having a hard time wrapping my head around command arguments for some reason.

Comment: Why? The command line arguments are just an array of strings. You know how to compare strings in Java don't you?

Comment: This is my first exposure to command line arguments. I was unaware, as Adrian explained to me, that arg contains the parameters passed to the command line. That one sentence made everything clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arg contains the parameters passed to the command line, i.e. if you call the prog with `prog.jar XML S xmltest.xml`:

```
String fileType = arg[0]; // == XML
String material = arg[1]; // == S
String fileName = arg[2]; // == xmltest.xml
if (fileType.equals("XML") && material.equals("S")) {
    parseXMLStudentFile(fileName);
} else { // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why that was so hard for me to understand. Must just be the school finals blues. Much appreciated.